# Sort list of object by date

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of dicts that look like this

```
"Tournaments": [
      {
        "Scrambling": "61.90",
        "Total_Putts_GIR": 85,
        "SG_Putting": 0.99,
        "Tournament": "Sony_Open",
        "Date": "01-09-2020"
      },
      {
        "Scrambling": "68.75",
        "Total_Putts_GIR": 93,
        "SG_Putting": 1.1,
        "Tournament": "Waste_Management",
        "Date": "01-30-2020"
      },
      {
        "Scrambling": "64.71",
        "Total_Putts_GIR": 70,
        "SG_Putting": -0.26,
        "Tournament": "WGC_Mexico",
        "Date": "02-20-2020"
      },
      {
        "Scrambling": "57.14",
        "Total_Putts_GIR": 40,
        "SG_Putting": -1.45,
        "Tournament": "Charles_Schwab",
        "Date": "06-11-2020"
      },
      {
        "Scrambling": "73.68",
        "Total_Putts_GIR": 82,
        "SG_Putting": 1.65,
        "Tournament": "RBC_Heritage",
        "Date": "06-18-2020"
      },
      {
        "Scrambling": "66.67",
        "Total_Putts_GIR": 92,
        "SG_Putting": 0.34,
        "Tournament": "Rocket_Mortgage",
        "Date": "07-02-2020"
      },
      {
        "Scrambling": "83.33",
        "Total_Putts_GIR": 101,
        "SG_Putting": 1.19,
        "Tournament": "Shriners_Hospital_for_Children_Open",
        "Date": "10-08-2019"
      }
    ]
```

I used

```
for obj in player_stats:
    for tournament in obj['Tournaments']:
        obj['Tournaments'].sort(key=operator.itemgetter('Date'))
```

to sort them however, it puts 2019 at the bottom. When I add `reverse=True` it reverses the months as well. I tried using `obj['Tournaments'].sort(key=lambda x: tournament['Date'])`, but this just returns the dicts in the same order. I need to return the list of dicts sorted by year 2019, 2020, then sorted by month, then sorted by day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a sort key of format YYYYMMDD.  (Your dates are in format MM-DD-YYYY.)

```
obj['Tournaments'].sort(key=lambda t:
                        t["Date"][6:] + t["Date"][:2] + t["Date"][3:5])

print(list(t["Date"] for t in obj["Tournaments"]))
```

gives:

```
['10-08-2019', '01-09-2020', '01-30-2020', '02-20-2020', '06-11-2020', '06-18-2020', '07-02-2020']
```

Comment: @AustinJohnson You're welcome. By the way, using a tuple instead of string concatenation would also work: `(t["Date"][6:], t["Date"][:2], t["Date"][3:5])`

Answer (score 1):

The dates are represented as strings and sorted lexicographically. This is why, for example, `'10-08-2019'` is ordered after `'07-02-2020'`.

A workaround would be to parse the strings into `datetime.datetime` objects for the purpose of sorting.

```py
from datetime import datetime
...
        key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x['Date'], '%m-%d-%Y')
        obj['Tournaments'].sort(key=key)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

***Another option*** could be to sort the dictionaries using `pandas` library. Now, this could be debatable as sometimes you may not need to bring in pandas, however, it would depend on the kind of problem/requirement that you are working on. It is often easier to visualize and process the data with pandas as well.

I would leave it to you to determine if you want to use pandas for this task or not, while I leave a note on how easily you could visualize the result and sort it with pandas.

```py
import pandas as pd

for obj in player_stats:    
    obj['Tournaments'] = pd.DataFrame(obj['Tournaments']).sort_values(['Date']).T.to_dict(orient='records')
```

### Load and sort the list of dictionaries

The one-line solution is this:

```py
pd.DataFrame(obj['Tournaments']).sort_values(['Date']).to_dict(orient='records')
```

Let us break it up to understand what it is doing.

#### A. Sort the `DataFrame`

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(obj['Tournaments']).sort_values(['Date'])
print(df) # print sorted dataframe
```

[image]

#### B. Convert the `DataFrame` into a `dict`

```
# convert DataFrame to dict
d = df.to_dict(orient='records') 
# print dictionary using json library
print(json.dumps(d, indent=2)
```

**Output**:

```
[{'Date': '01-09-2020',
  'SG_Putting': 0.99,
  'Scrambling': '61.90',
  'Total_Putts_GIR': 85,
  'Tournament': 'Sony_Open'},
 {'Date': '01-30-2020',
  'SG_Putting': 1.1,
  'Scrambling': '68.75',
  'Total_Putts_GIR': 93,
  'Tournament': 'Waste_Management'},
 {'Date': '02-20-2020',
  'SG_Putting': -0.26,
  'Scrambling': '64.71',
  'Total_Putts_GIR': 70,
  'Tournament': 'WGC_Mexico'},
 {'Date': '06-11-2020',
  'SG_Putting': -1.45,
  'Scrambling': '57.14',
  'Total_Putts_GIR': 40,
  'Tournament': 'Charles_Schwab'},
 {'Date': '06-18-2020',
  'SG_Putting': 1.65,
  'Scrambling': '73.68',
  'Total_Putts_GIR': 82,
  'Tournament': 'RBC_Heritage'},
 {'Date': '07-02-2020',
  'SG_Putting': 0.34,
  'Scrambling': '66.67',
  'Total_Putts_GIR': 92,
  'Tournament': 'Rocket_Mortgage'},
 {'Date': '10-08-2019',
  'SG_Putting': 1.19,
  'Scrambling': '83.33',
  'Total_Putts_GIR': 101,
  'Tournament': 'Shriners_Hospital_for_Children_Open'}]
```

### Dummy Data

I prefer to keep a record of the sample/dummy data provided in the question and the one used for the answer for the sake of reproducibility.

```py
obj = {
    "Tournaments": [
      {
        "Scrambling": "61.90",
        "Total_Putts_GIR": 85,
        "SG_Putting": 0.99,
        "Tournament": "Sony_Open",
        "Date": "01-09-2020"
      },
      {
        "Scrambling": "68.75",
        "Total_Putts_GIR": 93,
        "SG_Putting": 1.1,
        "Tournament": "Waste_Management",
        "Date": "01-30-2020"
      },
      {
        "Scrambling": "64.71",
        "Total_Putts_GIR": 70,
        "SG_Putting": -0.26,
        "Tournament": "WGC_Mexico",
        "Date": "02-20-2020"
      },
      {
        "Scrambling": "57.14",
        "Total_Putts_GIR": 40,
        "SG_Putting": -1.45,
        "Tournament": "Charles_Schwab",
        "Date": "06-11-2020"
      },
      {
        "Scrambling": "73.68",
        "Total_Putts_GIR": 82,
        "SG_Putting": 1.65,
        "Tournament": "RBC_Heritage",
        "Date": "06-18-2020"
      },
      {
        "Scrambling": "66.67",
        "Total_Putts_GIR": 92,
        "SG_Putting": 0.34,
        "Tournament": "Rocket_Mortgage",
        "Date": "07-02-2020"
      },
      {
        "Scrambling": "83.33",
        "Total_Putts_GIR": 101,
        "SG_Putting": 1.19,
        "Tournament": "Shriners_Hospital_for_Children_Open",
        "Date": "10-08-2019"
      }
    ]
}
```